# Pass a function as an argument to another function in .vimrc

Tags: function, vim, arguments

I have two functions in my .vimrc:

```
function! DoStuff()
    ...
endfunction

function! DoStuffWrapper(func)
    ...
    func
    ...
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader> ...
```

Basically that works. But I'm not sure if it is the right thing to do. Are there better alternatives to pass a function inside another function?

I saw approaches like

```
function! AFunction()
    ...
    :call call (function('FunctionName'), params)
    ...
endfunction
```

but that does only seem to work while using the functions name and not an argument.

Comment: The arguments are passed to the second function via the `params` argument.

Comment: Huh? Your first example will yield `Not an editor command: func`; as you're passing the _result_ of `DoStuff()` into the wrapper.

Comment: Ah sorry, there's an error in the example. I don't call the functions with àutocmd` but with a mapping.

Comment: Corrected the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `call DoStuffWrapper(DoStuff())` however it does **not** pass `DoStuff()` function to the wrapper, but the result of `DoStuff()`. think about this: `echo len(getline('.'))` same situation as yours.

I hope this example could explain a little bit for you:

```
fun! Sq(val)
    return a:val*a:val
endf


fun! SqRoot(val)
    return sqrt(a:val)
endf

fun! CalcFunc(val, func)
    echo a:func(a:val)
endf
```

so you want to pass a function to the `CalcFunc`, so that it could do dynamic calculation.

now if you do:

```
call CalcFunc(2, function('SqRoot'))
```

it will echo `1.414214`

and if you do:

```
call CalcFunc(2, function('Sq'))
```

it will echo `4`.

Comment: Thanks, lights are on now. :)